# Gadget Hosting on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-gadget

I have recently been tasked with working on creating a gadget for a
project that is hosted on app engine. I am also hosting the gadget
specification on app engine.

The gadget specification is generated on the server side as it refers
back to the application id that the gadget is hosted on (this project
may be hosted on multiple IDs), so I suspect that the gadget is
subject to the same start up times that application is subject to when
it has been inactive for a period of time (I don't know that this has
anything to do with the issue I am having).

Now to my problems. I have observed the following behavior:

1. After coming back to the mail inbox that I installed the gadget to
   the gadget has more often that not disappeared from the left side
   menu.
2. I came back to the mailbox after leaving Firefox open for an
   extended period of time, and after trying to use my gadget I received
   a 504 error "Unable to retrieve gadget spec"

Are these related? Does anyone have experience with this issue? The
gadget itself is working great hosted on app engine aside from this.

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely to be an App Engine issue. Have you checked the logs in your admin console to see what happens when it attempts to fetch the gadget spec, but fails?